# using pstricks to typeset a LaTeX document in Visual Studio Code

Tags: pstricks, dvips, visual-studio-code

I would like to start using Visual Code Studio LaTeX files. I am a linguist, and my documents contain many phrase marker trees that are written with macros that rely on pstricks. I therefore need to be able to typeset through postscript files. With the editor I use now (TextMate), I do this by going through the ancient latex+dvips+ps2pdf route. I haven't been able to figure out how to do that using the LaTeX Workshop extension in Visual Code Studio. Is there a better, more modern, way of doing what I need?

Comment: You can compile with `xelatex --shell-escape`.

Comment: Or with `pdflatex` and the `auto-pst-pdf` package (also requires shell-escape).

Comment: you can run your document with `lualatex`, `xelatex`, `pdflatex` with package `auto-pst-pdf` and/or with `latex`. I always prefer the first one: `lualatex` which directly creates a pdf.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answers. The LaTeX Workshop extension for Visual Studio code seems to merrily run pdflatex when asked to, but I do not see how to cause it to use the auto-pst-pdf package.

Comment: @Kyle: Why don't you use `lualatex`?  Then you do not need additional packages? And you can use every font which is on your system.